# schedule backup through PS_QUERY PeopleTools 8.49 and through cron/bath job

Tags: peoplesoft

> I have two question Ist one how to take backup of tables and schedule
>   it through PT 8.49 ps_query and 2nd is how to schedule a backup from
>   client side through cron jobs.My backup script for datamover which i
>   using for taking manual backup are:-

1. - SET NO TRACE;
   - SET LOG D:\BACKUP_PROD\backup_6tables_28 jUly2015 CU.log;
   - SET OUTPUT D:\BACKUP_PROD\backup_6tables_28 jUly2015CU.dat;
   - "ADM APPL TBLs" EXPORT adm_appl_prog where emplid like 'UF15%';
   - EXPORT adm_appl_plan where emplid like 'UF15%' ;
   - EXPORT adm_appl_sbplan where emplid like 'UF15%' ;
   - EXPORT adm_app_car_seq where emplid like 'UF15%' ;
   - EXPORT adm_appl_data where emplid like'UF15%' ;
   - EXPORT PS_SAD_STD_APP_NLD where emplid like 'UF15%' ;

Answer (score 0):

You can execute DMS scripts via the command line.  So create a script that executes via schedule with whichever operating system you are on.

example:
`psdmtx -CT dbtype [-CS server] -CD database_name 
-CO user_ID -CP user_password[-CI connect_ID -CW connect_password] 
[-I process_instance] -FP dms_filepath`